# Relationship with ID field but display text values in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am new to Access, have run into difficulty displaying text instead of ID numbers after migrating a few databases from Excel.

In my main table, I have a list of fields which have values as follows:

```
Variable1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Variable2 = {1, 2}
Variable3 = (4, 5}
```

Each variable has a relationship to the ID column of a separate table which enumerates the integer values eg. for variable 1:

```
ID    Value
1     Beer
2     Vodka
3     Other random booze
4     Rum
```

In my main table, the values are listed as integer values rather than text. Firstly, is there a way to maintain the relationship to the ID number in the secondary table, but display text values rather than integers?

Secondly, whilst I want to work with the text in Access, I would still like to export the data by ID number (specifically to statistical packages eg SPSS). Is it possible to set up the relationship so it works in this manner?

(To clarify, I had previously stored the values as integers in Excel, with the "Key"s in a separate sheet)

Thanks!

Comment: Where is it you are trying to display this information?  On a form or in a query?

Comment: I am trying to display information as IDs in the datasheet, but to display values in both forms and queries.

Answer (score 0):

To link the values so that you can display another column from the second table you need to perform a join.  This will let you join your tables on a certain value but display another column.

```
SELECT table1.Field1, table2.Field2
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Field1 = table2.Field1
```